# delete Single Core Data Item from a uicollectionviewCell using a button

Tags: swift, core-data, uicollectionview, protocols, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to delete a single element of the coreData set using a button inside a collectionviewcell. So the cell has a label with the result of the core data fetch. When I hit the button it should delete the cell making it no longer appear. Also the the core data single set item should be perementley deleted. I have scence this used before in protocols but not using core data.The core data is var itemName.

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
 @objc func delete() {
}}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var itemName : [Item] = []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In My Case Working 100%
Try This**

```
import CoreData 


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell Identifier name ", for: indexPath) as! Cellname
    cell.YourButtonNamw.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.YourButtonNamw.addTarget(self, action: #selector(delete), for: .touchUpInside)
     return cell
    }

     @objc func delete(_ sender:UIButton){
      let itemName1 = itemName[sender.tag]
     let context = APP_DELEGATE.persistentContainer.viewContext
            var albums = [YourTableName]()
            let request = NSFetchRequest<YourTableName>(entityName: YourTableName)
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemName = %@" , itemName1)
            do
            {
                albums = try context.fetch(request)

                for entity in albums {
                    context.delete(entity)
                    do
                    {
                        try context.save()

                    }
                    catch let error as Error?
                    {
                        print(error!.localizedDescription)

                    }
                }

            }
            catch _ {
                print("Could not delete")

            }

    }
```

Comment: Is  var albums = [YourTableName]() a core data entity?

Comment: Can you look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58313858/presently-delete-core-data-item-in-uicollectionviewcell-through-tag?noredirect=1#comment102990104_58313858. I have made some progress but cant get it to delete from core data.