# presently delete core data item in uicollectionviewcell through tag

Tags: swift, core-data, tags, indexpath

I am trying to permanently delete a single element from a core data set. Right now the code below removes the core data item but it does not permanently delete it. Once the class is called again it shows up again like nothing happened. I want it permanently deleted.

```
  func loadData() {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetch = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")
    do {
        self.itemName = try managedContext.fetch(fetch)
    }
    catch {
        print("Could not load. \(error)")
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadData()
}
      var itemName : [Item] = []
      @objc func elete(_ sender:UIButton){
    itemName.remove(at: sender.tag)
     collectionView.reloadData()

    }
```

Comment: Your delete method doesn't delete from CoreData, can you at least share how you set the itemNave value? Then maybe one of us can give some feedback on how to delete the object from core data.  Or share what you have tried for deleting from core data.

Comment: Added how I fetch my core data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete Single Core Data Item from a uicollectionviewCell using a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58293724/delete-single-core-data-item-from-a-uicollectionviewcell-using-a-button)